# Как сделать исключение для конкретного файла в nginx.conf

Tags: nginx

Всем привет! Имеется связка nginx + websocket-server. Часть содержимого nginx.conf такая:

```
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    ''      close;
}

server {
    server_name 192.168.1.20;
    listen 192.168.1.20:80 default_server;
    root /home/g-project/application;
    index index.htm;

    location /ws {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;        
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/g-project/service/gpro.sock;
        proxy_read_timeout 1h;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_buffering off;
    }
}
```

Если в запросе попадается подстрока /ws, то nginx проксирует запрос на websocket-server, иначе отрабатывает сам. Все работает норм, но при этом не получается загрузить файл ws.js, находящийся в корне проекта. Как конкретно этот файл настроить в конфиге nginx, чтобы он отдавался nginx'ом без проблем?

Comment: думаю, лучче будет написать `location = /ws {}`

Comment: Файл ws.js загружается, но зато теперь nginx не проксирует запросы  /ws/admin на бэкенд

Comment: в такой ситуации я бы выбирал максимально простые решения. переложить ws.js в каталог. или сделать 2 (или сколько там нужно) locaion для вебсокетов (`= /ws` и `= /ws/admin` или `= /ws-client` и `= /ws-admin`).

Comment: Проще было написать location /ws/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отвечаю сам:

```
location = /ws.js {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}

location /ws {
    ...
}
```